# Value not being passed via jQuery .val()/setItem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was given a snipped of code to update our hosted buyer site where we can only add JavaScript and CSS (no HTML directly) which was meant to allow quick ordering by adding the product directly to the cart (via an hidden iframe). The code works for the most part but it does not send the quantity correctly. We only ever get the minimum amount, rather than the amount the user input.

The first commented line was the original quantity input, but we had to edit it be restrictive of the way we sell this product. I cannot get the open entry field or the drop down to work.

```
    if ($(this).attr ("onclick").toLowerCase().indexOf("boxed") == -1)
    {
        $(this).before ('<select class = "dropdownPicker" id="' + $(this).attr ("id")  + '_quantity"> <option value="6">6</option> <option value="12">12</option> <option value="18">18</option> <option value="24">24</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="36">36</option></select>');
        //$(this).before ("<input id='" + $(this).attr ("id")  + "_quantity' value='1' style='width:40px'>");
        // changes the on click link to be executed on the new iframe, and adds an alert.
        $(this).attr ("onclick", $(this).attr ("onclick").replace ("location.href", "alert('Product will be added to the shopping cart');localStorage.setItem('selectedQuantity', $('#" + $(this).attr ("id")  + "_quantity').val());hiddenFrameForLink.location.href"));
        // replaces the a target to remote location
        $(this).attr ("target", "hiddenFrameForLink");
        // changes the caption of the button.
        $(this).text ("Add to Cart");
    }
```

Comment: Try removing all those spaces you have on all the methods. Why do you create them like that?

Comment: I just did that and so no difference. I didn't write them, they were given to me that way.

Answer (score 0):

You have an `onclick` handler, but that's not the way to detect what a user chooses from a `select` - it will fire when they first click on it, to display the dropdown, before they've chosen anything.

You need to use `onchange`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow. The value is pulled when they hit a separate button based on what is the current value in the drop down (or at least that's the goal). None of the onclicks (I believe) trigger off the drop down.

Comment: I see. Is the alert triggered?  Where is the code that retrieves the value from localStorage?